# tacacs client scriipt md-5 ...again

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I am having problems with creating a TACACS+ client side script.  I get a response back that my keys don't match from the server, (7, 0, 57, 0, b'10.163.255.107 : Invalid AUTHEN/START packet (check keys)', b''), but I can decode that from the tac_plus server so somewhere the keys do match.  Also, I have the tac_plus server in debug mode and see the same values for the first four or five bytes, then the data changes. Yet, all the hash values in the script match the hash values on the server.  I'm wondering if it's in string to bytes conversion.  Below is where I generate the hashes for taca_plus

```
def encrypt(packet, tac_key):
    seed = packet[4:8] + bytes(tac_key, 'utf-8') + packet[:1] + packet[2:3]

    hash = None
    while 1:
        if hash is None:
            hash = MD5.new(seed).digest()
        else:
            hash = MD5.new(seed + hash).digest()
        for char in hash:
            yield char
```

I pack the tac_plus /tacacs body first.

```
def tac_body(user, data, rem_addr='10.163.255.201', port="TCP49"):
    user_len = len(user)
    port_len = len(port)
    rem_addr_len = 0
    data_len = len(data)
    fmt = "! B B B B B B B B %ds %ds %ds" % (user_len, port_len, data_len)
    body = struct.pack(fmt, TAC_AUTHEN_LOGIN, TAC_PLUS_PRIV_LVL_USER, TAC_PLUS_AUTHEN_TYPE_PAP,
                   TAC_PLUS_AUTHEN_SVC_LOGIN, user_len, port_len, rem_addr_len, data_len,
                   bytes(user, 'utf-8'), bytes(port, 'utf-8'), bytes(data, 'utf-8'))
    return body
```

Then encrypt with this...

```
encrypted_data = ''.join([chr(operator.xor(c[0], c[1])) for c in zip(body, encrypt(header, tac_key))])
```

I am starting to get convinced that it has something to do with the tac_key string since I can change hash values by changing the encoding.

Comment: Why not try unencrypted first?

Comment: In what way?  Do you mean remove the tacacs key altogether and do an asiii login or do you mean create the hashes on encrypted data?

Comment: According to the [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-grant-tacacs-02) (page 6), `TACACS+` has the option to send unencrypted packets.

Comment: Yea, but I have to make it work with all of the md5 data obfuscation stuff.  Wouldn't hurt as a test though :)

Comment: BTW, there is something wrong with the indentation of your functions. They don't make sense as-is.

Comment: @MitchRaful: have reformatted the code segments, please confirm they correctly reflect your original intent.

Answer (score -1):

In the meantime I figured it all out.  When I send the encrypted portion, I had to encode it in latin-1.

```
msg = header + bytes(encrypted_data, encoding='latin-1')`
```

Go figure.

Comment: Note that the values 0-31 and 127-159 are not latin-1 and not displayable. What is really needed to to use an encoding that handles all values, hexadecimal and Base64 are the most common. Or just use an array of bytes if they do not need top be displayable. See [ISO/IEC 8859-1, Latin alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).